# Excel incorrectly filtered out rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a huge column that contains 60k+ different phone numbers.
When I filter out any bad cell e.g. [abcde] (That is the only one in column) by uncheck [abcde] row on filtering popup, Excel just hide over 50k+ well-formatted rows including that [abcde] row.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you, exactly, filter them out?

Comment: I am going to suggest **you** are doing something wrong not Excel, but without any more information I cannot really provide much more of an answer, please elaborate on the problem a bit more to enable someone on the site to help.

Comment: How did you filter? Could you provide the detail steps or pictures?